# compare tow string with == and strcmp

Tags: php, string

Php code

```
$test='00000000000000000000000000000001';
if($test==1)
   echo 'yes1 ';
if($test=="1")
   echo 'yes2 ';
if((string)$test==1)
   echo 'yes3 ';
if((string)$test=="1")
   echo 'yes4 ';
if((string)$test=="00000000000000000000000000000001")
   echo 'yes5 ';
```

[Online Code](https://ideone.com/5idafG)

why all condition are true? realy `(string)$test` is equal to "1"?

but when use `strcmp($test,"00000000000000000000000000000001")` this correct reutrn 0 and for `strcmp($test,"1")` return -1?

why?

Comment: Read about [PHP type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) and [loose comparison using "=="](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php). [`strcmp()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strcmp.php), on the other hand, compares two strings (converts the arguments to strings if they are not) character by character.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`==` (and `!=`) doesn't compare the type only the value.

Since `'00001'` is a string and `1` is an int then these are converted into the same type in order to compare.

In this case `'00001'` is converted to an int - `1`. `1 == 1` is true.

In order to exactly match on type you should use `===` and `!==`.

Comment: And what is with: `if($test == "1")` (quoted:) *these are converted into the same type*, Why are they evaluated as `true` ?

Comment: Because these are both numeric strings they will be treated as numbers before being compared.

Answer (score 3):

Please read about php type juggling. It is explained there.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Also check out comparison operators.
http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Answer (score 1):

[Doc](http://php.net/manual/language.operators.comparison.php) and [doc](http://php.net/manual/language.types.type-juggling.php).

`==` compare after type juggling.
`===` compare also the type.